# How to do a parallel unique word count with Java 8 streams and lambdas?

Tags: java, lambda, mapreduce, word-count, java-stream

What's the best way to do a parallel unique word count with Java 8 streams and lambdas?

I've come up with a couple, but I'm not convinced they are optimal.
I know the map reduce solution on Hadoop, and wonder if these give the same kind of parallelism.

```
// Map Reduce Word Count 

Map<String, Integer> wordCount = Stream.of("dog","cat","dog","dog","cow","house","house").parallel().collect( Collectors.groupingBy(e->e,Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)));
System.out.println("number of dogs = " + wordCount.get("dog"));

Map<Object, Object> wordCount2 = Stream.of("dog","cat","dog","dog","cow","house","house").parallel().collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(keyWord->keyWord, keyWord->1, (oldVal,newVal)->(int)oldVal+(int)newVal));
System.out.println("number of dogs = " + wordCount2.get("dog"));
```

Assume the real list would be much longer, possibly coming from a file or generated stream, and that I want to know the counts for all words, not just dog.

Comment: The first one looks fine. Note: short lists are usually better to single thread, and it would be faster to use a filter/count for your example.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify looking for all word counts on long lists.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the javadocs of `Collectors.groupingBy`

> @implNoteThe returned Collector is not concurrent. For parallel stream
>   pipelines, the combiner function operates by merging the keys from one
>   map into another, which can be an expensive operation. If preservation
>   of the order in which elements are presented to the downstream
>   collector is not required, using groupingByConcurrent(Function,
>   Supplier, Collector) may offer better parallel performance.

Now, looking at `Collectors.groupingByConcurrent` you'll see that that is more or less equivalent to your second approach

> Returns a concurrent Collector implementing a cascaded "group by"
>   operation on input elements of type T, grouping elements according to
>   a classification function, and then performing a reduction operation
>   on the values associated with a given key using the specified
>   downstream Collector. The ConcurrentMap produced by the Collector is
>   created with the supplied factory function.

Comment: OK, thanks. I was surprised there was no standard example for how to do this famous problem from Hadoop's examples

Comment: simply reading the javadocs beyond the method of interest usually is helpful, there often are related methods that may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The `groupingBy` and `toMap` might work slower on big datasets compared to `groupingByConcurrent` and `toConcurrentMap`. The best way to check whether `groupingByConcurrent` or `toConcurrentMap` is faster is to benchmark them by yourself on your own data sets. I think the results would be pretty much the same.

Note however that if you use the file as the source, you may probably have less speedup from parallelism as in Java 8 the `Files.lines()` and `BufferedReader.lines()` are reading files sequentially and parallelism is achieved by prebuffering blocks of lines into arrays and spawning new tasks. This not always works efficiently, so probably the bottleneck would be in this procedure. In JDK 9 `Files.lines()` is optimized (for regular files less than 2Gb long), thus you may get much better performance there.

As for generated sources it depends on how you generate them. It would be better if you supply the good splitting strategy for your source. If you use `Stream.iterate` or `Spliterators.spliterator(iterator, ...)` or extend `AbstractSpliterator` class, the default splitting strategy would be the same: prebuffer some elements into array to spawn a subtask.

Answer (score 1):

explaining Lee's code:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> wordCount(Stream<String> stream) {
    return stream
       .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.split("\\s+")))
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> 1, Integer::sum)); 
}
```

s -> s: key mapper

s -> 1: value mapper

Integer::sum: merger function

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Map<String, Integer> wordCount(Stream<String> stream) {
    return stream
       .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.split("\\s+")))
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> 1, Integer::sum)); 
}
```